# Not deducible relationship

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Why the relationship between `a` and `b` is not deducible?

```
class Vector a where
    (<.>) :: Num b => a -> a -> b

data Vec2 a
    = Vec2 (a, a)

    deriving Show

instance Num a => Vector (Vec2 a) where
    Vec2 (a, b) <.> Vec2 (c, d) = a * c + b * d
```

I would like to have a Vec2 algebric data structure where components can be any numbers.

Comment: [Here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.8.7/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html)'s the standard implementation of the vector space class. As you'll see it uses `Scalar` as an associated type family, like Ørjan suggested. (The class with `<.>` is actually a subclass, [`InnerSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.8.7/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#t:InnerSpace): not all vector spaces permit a scalar/inner product; what they all permit is only multiplying vectors with scalars (`*^`) and adding vectors together (`^+^` from `AdditiveGroup`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(<.>) :: Num b => a -> a -> b
```

The above means that `(<.>)` is able to produce *any* type of number the *caller* of that function might want.

For instance, if `x,y` are `Vec2 Double`, then `x <.> y` can be called to return `Integer`. The compiler then complains that its implementation in the posted instance is not general enough, because it returns `Double`s instead of *any* type the caller might choose.

I think this is not what that code was intended to model.

You might want to switch to a multiparameter class (you'll need to enable a few extensions, GHC will tell you which ones):

```
class Vector a b where
    (<.>) :: a -> a -> b

instance Num a => Vector (Vec2 a) a where
    Vec2 (a, b) <.> Vec2 (c, d) = a * c + b * d
```

Since now the compiler can not determine the type of `x <.> y` from the type of `x,y`, you might want to add a functional dependency using

```
class Vector a b | a -> b where
    (<.>) :: a -> a -> b
```

or alternatively to use a type family

```
class Vector a where
    type Scalar a
    (<.>) :: a -> a -> Scalar a

instance Num a => Vector (Vec2 a) where
    type Scalar (Vec a) = a
    Vec2 (a, b) <.> Vec2 (c, d) = a * c + b * d
```

Answer (score 2):

As @chi's answer said, your code doesn't make `b` depend on `a`. To get what I think you want, you can use an associated type family:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Vector a where
    type Element a
    (<.>) :: a -> a -> Element a

data Vec2 a
    = Vec2 (a, a)

    deriving Show

instance Num a => Vector (Vec2 a) where
    type Element (Vec2 a) = a
    Vec2 (a, b) <.> Vec2 (c, d) = a * c + b * d
```

Another option is to use a multiparameter typeclass with a functional dependency, but I think that's more complicated here.